# Why doesn't this if statement work properly

Tags: c#, if-statement, exchangewebservices

This code is designed to perform a cleanup after a mailbox rehydration (from Symantec Enterprise Vault). We take a snapshot index of the `MessageId` and `ConversationId` of all items in the mailbox before the rehydration.

After the rehydration this code

```
    if (string.Equals(item.ItemClass, "IPM.Note.EnterpriseVault.Shortcut", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) || ((existingIds.Any(x => x.ConversationId == item.ConversationId.ToString()) == false || (item.ItemClass == "IPM.Appointment" && existingIds.Any(x => x.MessageId == item.Id.ToString()) == false) && item.DateTimeReceived < snapshotDate)))
    {
        item.Delete(DeleteMode.HardDelete);
    }
```

should delete

1. Any items which have an `ItemClass` of "IPM.Note.EnterpriseVault.Shortcut"
2. Any items which have an `ItemClass` of "IPM.Appointment" where the `Id` is not in the `existingIds` list of `MessageId`s, unless they were received after the `snapshotDate
3. Any other items where the `ConversationId` is not in the `existingIds` list, unless they were received after the `snapshotDate`.

After running this code a user reported having lost some email that was received after the `snapshotDate` so it seems I have got the `if` statement wrong! :( Could somebody tell me please what I have got wrong (or a way that I can break this down to understand it better) and what this code will actually have done so I can let the user know what has been lost. I know lofical ORs are notoriously hard to get write and I think I have made a mistake with the brackets somewhere but I just can't see it.

Comment: Do you need to delete item which has ItemClass of "IPM.Note.EnterpriseVault.Shortcut" and received after the snapshotDate?

Comment: @OxQ There shouldn't be any items with an ItemClass of "IPM.Note.EnterpriseVault.Shortcut" after the snapshotDate but they can be deleted too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to split if check into local functions it will be much easier to debug.

```
 if (IsShourtcut(item) || NotExistingAppItment(item) || ExistingConversation(item) && IsReceivedBeforSnapshot(item)) 
    {
            // to delete 
    }

bool IsShourtcut(Item item) => string.Equals(item.ItemClass, "IPM.Note.EnterpriseVault.Shortcut", StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
bool NotExistingAppItment(Item item) => item.ItemClass == "IPM.Appointment" && existingIds.All(x => x.MessageId != item.Id.ToString());
bool ExistingConversation(Item item) => existingIds.All(x => x.ConversationId != item.ConversationId.ToString();
bool IsReceivedBeforSnapshot(Item item) => item.DateTimeReceived < snapshotDate;
```

Comment: Local functions is a great idea. For anybody else reading this you will need to use C# 7 or above for local functions but if that isn't an option then you could just use methods of the same class. I should also point out that although this was an extremely helpful answer it doesn't exactly match my stated problem as it doesn't take the date into account on existing Appointments.

Answer (score 1):

I find the easiest way to look at this sort of problem is to use lots of line breaks and indentation. I add a break and increase indentation after every `(` (except trivial `()`), bring matching `)`s below their matching pair and put the operators on separate lines between the items they're joining:

```
if (
    string.Equals(
        item.ItemClass,
        "IPM.Note.EnterpriseVault.Shortcut", StringComparison.InvariantCulture
    )
    ||
    (
        (
            existingIds.Any(
                x => x.ConversationId == item.ConversationId.ToString()
            ) == false
            ||
            (
                item.ItemClass == "IPM.Appointment"
                &&
                existingIds.Any(
                    x => x.MessageId == item.Id.ToString()
                ) == false
            )
            &&
            item.DateTimeReceived < snapshotDate
        )
    )
)
{
    item.Delete(DeleteMode.HardDelete);
}
```

I can immediately spot two things - there's a pair of parentheses that just contains another pair, and we have `&&` and `||` occurring at the same "level" so we're relying on operator precedence.

I'm guessing you wanted the `&&` outside of the inner parentheses so that it is applied against both the appointment check and the existing Ids one. E.g. this instead:

```
if (
    string.Equals(
        item.ItemClass,
        "IPM.Note.EnterpriseVault.Shortcut", StringComparison.InvariantCulture
    )
    ||
    (
        (
            existingIds.Any(
                x => x.ConversationId == item.ConversationId.ToString()
            ) == false
            ||
            (
                item.ItemClass == "IPM.Appointment"
                &&
                existingIds.Any(
                    x => x.MessageId == item.Id.ToString()
                ) == false
            )
        )
        &&
        item.DateTimeReceived < snapshotDate
    )
)
{
    item.Delete(DeleteMode.HardDelete);
}
```

(Once you've confirmed everything matches up as you need, you can collapse back down to fewer lines)

Comment: Excellent tip and good spot with the misplaced brackets. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both of the other answers to this were extremely helpful and I have upvoted accordingly. However I thought I would post my final solution to this as inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/61009776/470014 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/61008198/470014, leaning particularly heavily on the use of local functions as recommended by OxQ. I have now written unit tests (which I should have done earlier) and these all pass using my new method whereas five of them were failing before. I believe this code more closely matches the stated problem and is fairly straightforward to read and understand. I have had to use scalar values rather than the whole `Item` object, so I can unit test this as Exchange Web Services managed API doesn't use interfaces.

```
switch (itemClass)
{
    case "IPM.Note.EnterpriseVault.Shortcut":
        return true;
    case "IPM.Appointment":
        return NotExistingMessage() && IsReceivedBeforeSnapshot();
    default:
        return NotExistingConversation() && IsReceivedBeforeSnapshot();
}

bool NotExistingMessage() => existingIds.All(x => x.MessageId != messageId);
bool NotExistingConversation() => existingIds.All(x => x.ConversationId != conversationId);
bool IsReceivedBeforeSnapshot() => dateTimeReceived < uploadDate;
```